# How can I wrap the text contents of an element with a new tag?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have a `Nokogiri::XML::Element` in which looks like this:

```
<div class="berg">This is some text!</div>
```

What I want to do is just extract the text from the div (which is the Nokogiri Element) and then wrap the text with a new tag so it looks like this:

```
<div class="berg"><span>This is some text!</span></div>
```

The Nokogiri `.wrap` functions seems to wrap tags, not their text contents with a new tag, I was wondering how you wrap the inter tag contents.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the `inner_html` of the div element. Here's a working example:

```
html = '<div class="berg">This is some text!</div>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)

berg = doc.at('div.berg')    # Or xpath, or whatever method you choose

# Wrap the text in <span>
berg.inner_html = "<span>#{berg.text}</span>"

puts doc  #=> <div class="berg"><span>This is some text!</span></div>
```

The important part is the use of `inner_html`, adding in the `<span>` element and putting the existing text element inside it.

Comment: This will work only with simple text, if `text` contain some html content, then it fails, because `berg.text` just prints text content and removes HTML tags.

Answer (score 3):

You would do:

```
doc.search('div.berg text()').wrap('<span>')
```

Comment: very interesting. Could you explain this syntax `'div.berg text()'`?

Comment: Sure, it's basically a translation of `//div[@class="berg"]/text()` into css. Not standard css mind you but nokogiri lets us get away with it.

Comment: No, as far as I know it's undocumented.

Comment: Ohhkay! :( still it is nice lesson to me. Can every XPATH expression be converted to this kind of `css`?

Comment: Yes, when it comes to html (as opposed to xml), css is generally much simpler and more readable than xpath,